# change value in backing bean not reflected in UI

Tags: java, jsf

The component is wired via value binding to a backing bean property.

```
<h:inputText id="number" value="#{backingBean.number}" validator="#{backingBean.validateNumber}" />
```

In the validation method the number value is changed

```
public void validateNumber(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String inputValue = (String) value;

    if (inputValue.length() == 9) {
        inputValue = "0" + inputValue;
        ((UIInput) component).setSubmittedValue(inputValue);
        ((UIInput) component).setValue(inputValue);
        setNumber(inputValue);
    }
}
```

While debugging I can verify that the value is in fact being changed but during the rendering phase the new value is somehow overridden by the old value.
This must have something to do with me misunderstanding the JSF lifecycle, but the way I see it I am changing both the value op the property to which to component is bound in the UI and because I have a hook to the actual component I also change the component's value and submittedValue to be sure (to find the problem) and still the change isn't reflected int he UI?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. You should use a [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) for this, not a [`Validator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html). A validator is to *validate* the value, not to *change* (convert) the value.

```
public void EnterpriseNumberConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value.length() == 9) {
            value = "0" + value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (String) value;
    }

}
```

---

As to why it isn't possible in a validator, this is what is *basically* happening:

- Phase 2: apply request values (`input` is [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) and `request` is [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html))

  ```
  input.setSubmittedValue(request.getParameter(input.getClientId()));
  ```
- Phase 3: validation phase.

  ```
  Object value = input.getSubmittedValue();
  try {
      value = input.getConvertedValue(facesContext, value);
  } catch (ConverterException e) {
      // ...
      return;
  }
  try {
      for (Validator validator : input.getValidators())
          validator.validate(facesContext, input, value);
      }
      input.setSubmittedValue(null);
      input.setValue(value); // You see?
  } catch (ValidatorException e) {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Phase 4: update model values phase.

  ```
  bean.setProperty(input.getValue());
  ```

Comment: Fact is that first some validation occurs and at the end if the validation is ok but the number is 9 digits instead of 10 it must be edited to contain a leading 0. I left out the extra validation for the sake of brevity, but is it not possible at all to edit this value in t he validator method at all?? need I provide a converter apart from the validator method for just this? I understand that this is cleaner but I would like to know if it is technically possible to do this in the jsf lifecycle?